# Adding jar file to buildpath and got permission denied error

Tags: java

I have trying to understand the build process at a much finer level by doing all the building myself without a build tool, so I can understand and appreciate gradle more.

I have two folders in my Desktop, `gradle_demo` and `library-A`, `gradle_demo` has only one java file which is the main class. This class requires a dependency on `library-A`.

As you can see from below snapshot on my atom editor, under the `library-A`, I have two classes `DemoMathUtil.java` and `NetworkUtil.java`. I packaged the two java files into a jar and you can see the content on the right of the snapshot

So, in my `Program.java` file, I got this code:

```
import DemoMathUtil;

public class Program {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DemoMathUtil mu = new DemoMathUtil();
    mu.m1();
  }

}
```

It only used the `DemoMathUtil` class.

In the terminal, I wrote the following:

`Wings-MacBook-Pro:gradle_demo wingsuncheung$ javac -cp .;../library-A/demo.jar Program.java`

And this is the error I got:

`javac: no source files`

`bash: ../library-A/demo.jar: Permission denied`

Why is that? I feel like I have done everything correct, but the compiler denied my access to my own jar file.

Any clues? thanks

[image: Jars structure]

Comment: did you double check the permissions on the jar? just to test I would do this first: chmod 755 demo.jar

Comment: Permission on a jar? How does this happen? What is this permission?

Comment: Putting that line on the terminal doesnt ahow anythjng

Comment: on terminal navigate to the directory and just run ls -ltr
the first column gives you permissions on the file

Comment: The first column is -rwxr-xr-x

Comment: those are right and are result (maybe) of the chmod command. Try running your program now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200684/discussion-between-kaus-untwale-and-brendon-cheung).